# How can I vectorize this code?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

First of all I should say that I couldn't find the appropriate title for my question so I would appreciate anyone who will edit the title!
Suppose that I have a 18432x1472 matrix and I want to convert it to a 3072x1472 one ( 18432/6 = 3072 ) in this form:
the mean of elements (1,6),(2,6),...,(6,6) of the old matrix will go to the element (1,1) of the new one
the mean of elements (7,6),(8,6),...,(12,6) of the old matrix will go to the element (2,1) of the new one and so on
Up to now I have written this code:

```
function Out = MultiLooking( In )
   MatrixIn = double(In);
   m = size(In,1);
   InTranspose = MatrixIn';
   A = zeros(m,m/6);
   for i = 1:(m/6)
       A(6*(i-1)+1,i) = 1;
       A(6*(i-1)+2,i) = 1;
       A(6*(i-1)+3,i) = 1;
       A(6*(i-1)+4,i) = 1;
       A(6*(i-1)+5,i) = 1;
       A(6*(i-1)+6,i) = 1;
   end
   X = (InTranspose*A)/6;
   Out1 = X';
   Out = uint8(Out1);
end
```

But it is alittle slow and for my polarimetric SAR data, computer gets hanged out for a while when running this code so I need the code to run faster!
Can anyone suggest me a faster code for doing this purpose???

Comment: is it intended that the second list has (2,6) in it?

Comment: In `(7,6),(2,6),...,(12,6)`, shouldn't it be `(8,6)` instead of `(2,6)`?

Comment: @Jigg and Divakar you're right. It was just a typo and I have corrected that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative to [Divakar's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23817185/2586922): use [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) (Image Processing Toolbox):

```
blockproc(MatrixIn, [6 size(MatrixIn,2)], @(x) mean(x.data))
```

Comment: Many alternatives must be thrown at OPs! Makes life interesting on `SO` for them and us :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```
%// Assuming MatrixIn is your input matrix
reshape(mean(reshape(MatrixIn,6,[])),size(MatrixIn,1)/6,[])
```

Alternative Solution using cell arrays (performance improvement over previous code is doubtful though) -

```
c1 = cellfun(@mean,mat2cell(MatrixIn,6.*ones(1,size(MatrixIn,1)/6),size(MatrixIn,2)),'uni',0)
out = vertcat(c1{:})
```